# Why does rendering a png from this pdf using imagemagick create these streaky artifacts?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, png, imagemagick-convert, image-conversion

I'm running ghostscript 9.22, libpng 1.6.34, and imagemagick 7.0.7-11 Q16

Here is the command that replicates the issue:

```
convert -density 400 icon.pdf -scale 1024x1024 ./appicon-1024x1024.png
```

Here is a link to the input PDF:
https://www.pdf-archive.com/2017/12/06/icon/

Here is the output I see, with streaky horizontal line artifacts:
[image: app-icon]

Interestingly, turning off antialiasing resolves the issue, but is not suitable for our use case.

Comment: A quick workaround (pending the code to be reviewed) would be to convert without antialiasing to 2x, 4x, or more of the target size, then resizing that *with* antialiasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running into this same issue and I think that Ghostscript 9.22 is the problem. I can reproduce the issue by running Ghostscript directly:

`gs -dSTRICT -dDOINTERPOLATE -dNOPAUSE -dEPSCrop -dBATCH -sOutputFile=test.png -sDEVICE=pngalpha /path/to/broken.pdf`

I've also tested with Ghostscript 9.21, which works as expected.

When imagemagick's `convert` command is run with `+antialias`, it passes different switches to ghostscript.

You can use the `-verbose` switch to tell imagemagick to print out the entire command it is using to invoke `gs`:

`$ convert -verbose test.pdf test.png`

Which yields:

`'gs' -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pamcmyk32' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r72x72' -g1728x1728 -dEPSCrop  ...`

With the antialias flag set:

`$ convert -verbose +antialias test.pdf test-with-antialias-flag.png`

gives us:

`'gs' -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pamcmyk32' -dTextAlphaBits=1 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=1 '-r72x72' -g1728x1728 -dEPSCrop`

There are a couple of different switches set there. Based on some experimentation running `gs` directly, I figured out that `-dGraphicsAlphaBits` seems to be the culprit. If it is set to a value greater than 1, the lines appear in the output.

So there are a few potential workarounds:

- Edit imagemagick's delegates.xml to force `-dGraphicsAlphaBits` to 1.
- Install ghostscript 9.21, which seems unaffected.
- Convert at double dimensions and then size down, as suggested above.

Comment: neither editing delegates.xml nor converting with +antialisaing got me rid of the stripes.

Answer (score 1):

Update ghostscript to version 9.23 and reinstall imagemagick.

Answer (score 0):

This command works perfectly fine for me using ImageMagick 6.9.9.25 Q16 Mac OSX and Ghostscript 9.21 and libpng @1.6.30_0.

```
convert -density 400 icon.pdf -scale 1024x1024 test.png
```

[image]

I suspect it is either your Ghostscript or libpng version. Try upgrading.

Comment: I'm running ghostscript 9.22, libpng 1.6.34, and imagemagick 7.0.7-11 Q16, all of which ahead of your working versions.

Comment: I tried with IM 7.0.7.13 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra with Ghostscript 9.21 and libpng @1.6.30_0 and it still works fine for me.